# How to delete snowflake target table using Spark/PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to delete a target snowflake table which I have created using Pyspark in Databricks platform.

Any help guys, I could not find any solution.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: It's asking for lower and upper bound values

Comment: can you post error message... and your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the runQuery() method of the Utils object to execute DDL/DML SQL statements, in addition to queries, e.g.:

```
var sfOptions = Map(
    "sfURL" -> "<account_name>.snowflakecomputing.com",
    "sfAccount" -> "<account_name>",
    "sfUser" -> "<user_name>",
    "sfPassword" -> "<password>",
    "sfDatabase" -> "<database>",
    "sfSchema" -> "<schema>",
    "sfWarehouse" -> "<warehouse>",
    )
Utils.runQuery(sfOptions, "DROP TABLE MY_TABLE")
```

[Snowflake DDL spark](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#executing-ddl-dml-sql-statements)

Comment: Can you help to import this Utils in Pyspark please

Comment: I added import net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils and than it worked for me.

Comment: The Utils object referenced in the docs is for Scala, not for python. How did you import the Utils object in Python?